# How to remove all keys pointing to given value

Tags: kotlin

Let's have the following (mutable) map:

```
1   -> A
45  -> A
88  -> R
98  -> X
105 -> A
```

Now I want to remove all items pointing to `A`. I came up with the following code:

```kotlin
// Version 1
myMap.forEach { key, value -> if (value == "A") myMap.remove(key) }

// Version 2
with (myMap) {
    val filtered = filterValues { it != "A" }
    clear()
    putAll(filtered)
}
```

But somehow none of it seems right. So what is the correct, most elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to declare your map as a `Map` instead of a `MutableMap` and just overwrite it with a filtered version of itself:

```
var myMap = mapOf(1 to "A", 2 to "B")
myMap = myMap.filterValues { it != "A" }
println(myMap)
```

If you want the `MutableMap` (yet still a `var`) version, it's similar:

```
var myMap = mutableMapOf(1 to "A", 2 to "B")
myMap = myMap.filterValues { it != "A" } as MutableMap
println(myMap)
```

*Update*: Mario Topolnik correctly points out that casting here is more efficient than calling `.toMutableMap()` as a new copy is not created.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you like version 1? It's what I would use. Another option:

```
with(myMap.iterator()) {
    forEach { if (it.value == "A") remove() }
}
```

Though it also depends how many elements you expect to remove: only a few (then `remove` will probably be faster), or most (`filterValues` may be faster)?

Comment: Version 1 fails with `ConcurrentModificationException`, so your twist on it is required.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, makes sense.